# Spring Security authorization each request in REST app (without login form)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have POST request with something like this in my Spring project:

```
{"clientKey":"XXX", "accessKey":"ZZZ", ... }
```

My backend works in very simple paradigm: get `clientKey` (login) and `accessKey` (password) params from POST body, check their persistence in DB and then do some business logic.

I need to implement minimal security check logic using Spring Security for each incoming request (without sessions and tokens).

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
                .and().csrf().disable();
        http.addFilterBefore(new ApiAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

**ApiAuthorizationFilter.java**

```
public class ApiAuthorizationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) 
                    throws IOException, ServletException {
        //
        // always prints "{}", why?
        //
        Logger.getLogger("test").log(Level.INFO, request.getParameterMap().toString());

        //
        // Ok, I will make some manual auth operations for testing purposes.
        // Seems what it isn't work too..
        //
        Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>(1);
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                "94fc97a7b3fd2175472ec4a41bcb3b14",
                "746b2aa32fe90f0ba53e6efe7a8d1f1f", 
                authorities);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

What I doing wrong? Does UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter work only with login forms when submitted or I need another filter in security chain?